Extracting tempature from a thermal camera
With a Teledyne FLIR Hadron 640R thermal and RGB camera and an NVIDIA Jetson Nano Developer Kit - B01 I'm trying to extract metadata from thermal frames using GStreamer in Python3. The RGB attempts to start displaying but shuts down immediately and the IR doesn't even display:

Error received from element v4l2src1:Internal data stream error.
Debugging information: gstbasesrc.c(3055): gst_base_src_loop(): /GstPipeline1/GstV4l2src:v4l2src1:
Streaming stopped , reason not-negotiated(-4)

Not working code with temperature extraction:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime
import numpy as np
import gi  # type: ignore
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib  # type: ignore

# Initialize GStreamer
Gst.init(None)

# Pin Definitions
input_pin = 24  # Pin 24 as input

# Variables to manage the video capture
is_recording = False
rgb_pipeline = None
ir_pipeline = None
loop = GLib.MainLoop()

def convert_y16_to_8bit(frame):
    """Converts Y16 16-bit thermal image frame to 8-bit."""
    min_val = np.min(frame)
    max_val = np.max(frame)
    frame_8bit = ((frame - min_val) / (max_val - min_val) * 255).astype(np.uint8)
    return frame_8bit, min_val, max_val

def raw_to_celsius(raw_val):
    """Converts raw thermal camera value to degrees Celsius."""
    kelvin = raw_val * 0.01  # Example conversion factor, replace with correct one
    celsius = kelvin - 273.15
    return celsius

def create_pipeline(device, width, height, stream_url, file_prefix, timestamp, thermal=False):
    if thermal:
       pipeline_description = (
            f"v4l2src io-mode=4 device={device} do-timestamp=true ! "
            f"video/x-raw,format=GRAY16_LE,width={width},height={height},framerate=30/1 ! "
            "videoconvert ! "
            "tee name=i "
            "i. ! "
            "queue ! appsink name=sink emit-signals=True sync=false "
            "i. ! "
            "videoconvert ! "
            "video/x-raw,format=GRAY8 ! "
            "textoverlay name=overlay valignment=top halignment=left text='Temp: ' ! "
            "clockoverlay halignment=left valignment=bottom time-format=\"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" font-desc='Sans, 36' ! "
            "timeoverlay halignment=right valignment=bottom text=\"Stream time:\" font-desc='Sans, 24' ! "
            "tee name=t ! "
            "queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc bitrate=5000000 ! h264parse ! "
            "tee name=l ! "
            f"queue ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location='{stream_url} live=1' "
            "l. ! "
            f"queue ! qtmux ! filesink location=/home/nvidia/Desktop/{file_prefix}_{timestamp}.mp4 "
            "t. ! "
            "queue ! xvimagesink sync=false "
    )


    else:
        pipeline_description = (
        f"v4l2src io-mode=4 device={device} do-timestamp=true ! "
        f"video/x-raw, width={width}, height={height}, framerate=30/1 ! clockoverlay halignment=left valignment=bottom time-format= \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" font-desc='Sans, 36'! timeoverlay halignment=right valignment=bottom text= \"Stream time:\" font-desc='Sans, 24' ! "
        "tee name=t ! "
        "queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc bitrate=5000000 ! h264parse ! "
        "tee name=l ! "
        f"queue ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location='{stream_url} live=1' "
        "l. ! "
        f"queue ! qtmux ! filesink location=/home/nvidia/Desktop/{file_prefix}_{timestamp}.mp4 "
        "t. ! "
        "queue leaky=1 ! xvimagesink sync=false"
    )
    return Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_description)

def on_message_rgb(bus, message, loop):
    msg_type = message.type
    if msg_type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug_info = message.parse_error()
        print(f"Error received from element {message.src.get_name()}: {err.message}")
        print(f"Debugging information: {debug_info if debug_info else 'none'}")
        rgb_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        loop.quit()
    elif msg_type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("End-Of-Stream reached")
        rgb_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

def on_message_ir(bus, message, loop):
    msg_type = message.type
    if msg_type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug_info = message.parse_error()
        print(f"Error received from element {message.src.get_name()}: {err.message}")
        print(f"Debugging information: {debug_info if debug_info else 'none'}")
        ir_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        loop.quit()
    elif msg_type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("End-Of-Stream reached")
        ir_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

def new_sample(sink, data):
    sample = sink.emit('pull-sample')
    buf = sample.get_buffer()
    caps = sample.get_caps()
    array = np.ndarray(
        (caps.get_structure(0).get_value('height'),
         caps.get_structure(0).get_value('width')),
        buffer=buf.extract_dup(0, buf.get_size()),
        dtype=np.uint16)

    # Convert the frame and get min/max temperatures
    frame_8bit, min_raw, max_raw = convert_y16_to_8bit(array)
    min_temp = raw_to_celsius(min_raw)
    max_temp = raw_to_celsius(max_raw)

    # Find min and max locations
    min_loc = np.unravel_index(np.argmin(array), array.shape)
    max_loc = np.unravel_index(np.argmax(array), array.shape)

    # Update the textoverlay element with the min/max temperature and locations
    overlay = ir_pipeline.get_by_name('overlay')
    if overlay:
        overlay.set_property("text", f"Cold: {min_temp:.2f}C ({min_loc[1]},{min_loc[0]})  Hot: {max_temp:.2f}C ({max_loc[1]},{max_loc[0]})")

    return Gst.FlowReturn.OK

def start_rgb_recording():
    global rgb_pipeline, loop
    current_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    rgb_pipeline = create_pipeline('/dev/video0', 1920, 1080, 'rtmp://google.de/live/rgb', 'RGB', current_timestamp)
    bus_rgb = rgb_pipeline.get_bus()
    bus_rgb.add_signal_watch()
    bus_rgb.connect("message", on_message_rgb, loop)
    rgb_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    print("Starting RGB pipeline...")

def start_ir_recording():
    global ir_pipeline, loop
    current_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
    ir_pipeline = create_pipeline('/dev/video1', 640, 512, 'rtmp://google.de/live_lowres/ir', 'IR', current_timestamp, thermal=True)
    bus_ir = ir_pipeline.get_bus()
    bus_ir.add_signal_watch()
    bus_ir.connect("message", on_message_ir, loop)

    sink = ir_pipeline.get_by_name('sink')
    sink.connect('new-sample', new_sample, None)

    ir_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    print("Starting IR pipeline...")

def stop_rgb_recording():
    global rgb_pipeline
    if rgb_pipeline:
        rgb_pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
        time.sleep(1)
        rgb_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        print("RGB stopped")

def stop_ir_recording():
    global ir_pipeline
    if ir_pipeline:
        ir_pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
        time.sleep(1)
        ir_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        print("IR stopped")

def pin_callback(channel):
    global is_recording

    if GPIO.input(channel):
        print("Rising edge detected on pin", channel)
        if not is_recording:
            start_rgb_recording()
            start_ir_recording()
            is_recording = True
    else:
        print("Falling edge detected on pin", channel)
        if is_recording:
            stop_rgb_recording()
            stop_ir_recording()
            is_recording = False

def main():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # Use BCM pin numbering
    GPIO.setup(input_pin, GPIO.IN)  # Set pin 24 as input

    GPIO.add_event_detect(input_pin, GPIO.BOTH, callback=pin_callback, bouncetime=300)

    print("Starting demo now! Press CTRL+C to exit")
    try:
        #GLib.unix_signal_add(GLib.PRIORITY_HIGH, signal.SIGINT, handle_keyboard_interrupt, loop)
        loop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("stopping pipelines...")
        loop.quit()
        print("Pipelines stopped.")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

Working code without temperature extraction:
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime

import gi  # type: ignore
gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
from gi.repository import Gst, GLib  # type: ignore

# Initialize GStreamer
Gst.init(None)

# Pin Definitions
input_pin = 24  # Pin 24 as input

# Variables to manage the video capture
is_recording = False
rgb_pipeline = None
ir_pipeline = None
loop = GLib.MainLoop()

def create_pipeline(device, width, height, stream_url, file_prefix, timestamp):
    pipeline_description = (
        f"v4l2src io-mode=4 device={device} do-timestamp=true ! "
        f"video/x-raw, width={width}, height={height}, framerate=30/1 ! clockoverlay halignment=left valignment=bottom time-format= \"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S\" font-desc='Sans, 36'! timeoverlay halignment=right valignment=bottom text= \"Stream time:\" font-desc='Sans, 24' ! "
        "tee name=t ! "
        "queue ! nvvidconv ! nvv4l2h264enc bitrate=5000000 ! h264parse ! "
        "tee name=l ! "
        f"queue ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location='{stream_url} live=1' "
        "l. ! "
        f"queue ! qtmux ! filesink location=/home/nvidia/Desktop/{file_prefix}_{timestamp}.mp4 "
        "t. ! "
        "queue leaky=1 ! xvimagesink sync=false"
    )
    return Gst.parse_launch(pipeline_description)

def on_message_rgb(bus, message, loop):
    msg_type = message.type
    if msg_type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug_info = message.parse_error()
        print(f"Error received from element {message.src.get_name()}: {err.message}")
        print(f"Debugging information: {debug_info if debug_info else 'none'}")
        rgb_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        loop.quit()
    elif msg_type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("End-Of-Stream reached")
        rgb_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

def on_message_ir(bus, message, loop):
    msg_type = message.type
    if msg_type == Gst.MessageType.ERROR:
        err, debug_info = message.parse_error()
        print(f"Error received from element {message.src.get_name()}: {err.message}")
        print(f"Debugging information: {debug_info if debug_info else 'none'}")
        ir_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        loop.quit()
    elif msg_type == Gst.MessageType.EOS:
        print("End-Of-Stream reached")
        ir_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)

def start_recording():
    global is_recording, rgb_pipeline, ir_pipeline, loop

    current_timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")

    rgb_pipeline = create_pipeline('/dev/video0', 1920, 1080, 'rtmp://google/live/rgb', 'RGB', current_timestamp)
    ir_pipeline = create_pipeline('/dev/video1', 640, 512, 'rtmp://google.waldwaechter.de/live_lowres/ir', 'IR', current_timestamp)
    loop = GLib.MainLoop()
    bus_rgb = rgb_pipeline.get_bus()
    bus_ir = ir_pipeline.get_bus()
    bus_rgb.add_signal_watch()
    bus_ir.add_signal_watch()
    bus_rgb.connect("message", on_message_rgb, loop)
    bus_ir.connect("message", on_message_ir, loop)

    rgb_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    ir_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    print("Starting RGB and IR pipelines...")

def stop_recording():
    global is_recording, rgb_pipeline, ir_pipeline, loop

    if rgb_pipeline:
        rgb_pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
        time.sleep(1)
        rgb_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        print("RGB stopped")

    if ir_pipeline:
        ir_pipeline.send_event(Gst.Event.new_eos())
        time.sleep(1)
        ir_pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
        print("IR stopped")

def pin_callback(channel):
    global is_recording

    if GPIO.input(channel):
        print("Rising edge detected on pin", channel)
        if not is_recording:
            start_recording()
            is_recording = True
    else:
        print("Falling edge detected on pin", channel)
        if is_recording:
            stop_recording()
            is_recording = False

def main():
    GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)  # Use BCM pin numbering
    GPIO.setup(input_pin, GPIO.IN)  # Set pin 24 as input

    GPIO.add_event_detect(input_pin, GPIO.BOTH, callback=pin_callback, bouncetime=300)

    print("Starting demo now! Press CTRL+C to exit")
    try:
        #GLib.unix_signal_add(GLib.PRIORITY_HIGH, signal.SIGINT, handle_keyboard_interrupt, loop)
        loop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("stopping pipelines...")
        loop.quit()
        print("Pipelines stopped.")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()


do not tag opencv. this does not involve opencv.
